# Modify an incoming mail from text/plain to text/html

Tags: text-processing, email, mutt, fetchmail, procmail

I'm using [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) to process my mail. There is one sender which declares the wrong content type. The mail arrives with

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary=--…
```

and has two parts. They are declared as:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

and

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

However both parts of the mail are same. So the plaintext part is full of HTML tags as well as the HTML part. I've tried to discuss it with the sender, but they use some kind of 'enterprise' software where they cannot change those settings.

So I'd like to change the mail locally and maybe remove the `text/plain`-part or rewrite `text/plain` to `text/html`.

What do you consider the best way and what tools can I use to get a readable mail in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mutt, you can type <kbd>v</kbd>, and then select the alternative you want to display. You can also change the content-type of a part with <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>.

As a more generic approach, you could use `mutt`'s `display_filter` setting:

```
set display_filter=/path/to/mutt-filter
```

With `mutt-filter` being something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  cmd="echo '[automatically converted from html to text]'; w3m -T text/html -dump"
}
{l=tolower($0)}
l ~ /<html|<!doctype html/,l ~ /<\/html>/ {
  print | cmd
  next
}
{close(cmd); print}
```

Which would cause (in what `mutt` is going to display, not the raw email) anything between `<html>` and `</html>` to go through `w3m -T text/html -dump` (or `elinks -dump` or your preferred `html` to `text` converter).

As that might convert things that it's not meant to (like when `<html>` does appear in a genuine `text/plain` part), you might want to adapt it so that it only operates on emails from those guys that send bogus emails, or some even fancier approach like counting the number of tags and convert when reaching a threshold...

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of these possibilities. I'm looking more for an automated approach. <kbd>v</kbd> and HTML is set to open an external browser (and I'd like it to keep that way). <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> does only edit the content type of the whole mail not individual parts.

Comment: @qbi, if you type CTRL-E on the currently selected _part_, it edits that part's content-type.

Comment: @qbi, I've updated the answer with another possible approach.

Comment: @qbi, with `w3m`, you need to add `-T text/html`